# VB.NET - How do you change the namespace/class names for a "Windows application" from the default My.MyApplication?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using SharpDevelop and .NET 4.0.

My question is this: If you start a new project with a "Windows Application" template, it generates a Program.vb with the following contents:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
' This file controls the behaviour of the application.
     Partial Class MyApplication
         Public Sub New()
             MyBase.New(AuthenticationMode.Windows)
             Me.IsSingleInstance = False
             Me.EnableVisualStyles = True
             Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = True
             Me.ShutDownStyle = ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
         End Sub

         Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
             Me.MainForm = My.Forms.MainForm
         End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

However, if you change either the namespace or the class name, it breaks. I note that the wizard generates a Settings.settings file... What bothers me is that I can't seem to find the source of the class extension. That is, if you change either/both namespace/class, you get build errors such as:

```
Program.vb(22,27) : Error BC30284: sub 'OnCreateMainForm' 
cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a sub
in a base class.
```

In other words, in my mind the code should be something like:

```
Namespace My
    Partial Class MyApplication
        Inherits WindowsFormsApplicationBase
...
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you rename from the Solution explorer you will be okay.

If you refactor from the class, you could end up with Class1 defined in Class2.cs, which would be irritating.

If you just amend MyForm.cs, then you also need to amend MyForm.Designer.cs, which is where I suspect your problem is.