# How to inherit from WindowsFormsApplicationBase?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance

I have inherited (look at that, a pun, sorry...) a suite of VB.Net applications which share common functionality, currently "copy and paste" duplicated across all of them. I want to begin the refactoring process. Side note: I am primarily a C# developer, not too familiar with VB.

All of these VB applications are using the "Application Framework". One of the first things I tried to do is get all of them to inherit from a common application base class. I created a new class:

```
Namespace My
   Public Class ParentApplicationBase
      Inherits Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase
      Public Sub Bar()
         Console.WriteLine("Here we are in Bar()")
      End Sub
   End Class
End Namespace
```

Then, in ApplicationEvents.vb, ChildApp.vb, and Application.Designer.vb, I changed the

```
Partial Friend MyApplication
```

to

```
Partial Friend MyApplication : Inherits ParentApplicationBase
```

However, that results in the error:

> Base class 'ParentApplicationBase' specified for class 'MyApplication'
>   cannot be different from the base class
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase'
>   of one of its other partial types.

I have double and tripled checked that all of my partial classes are indeed inheriting from ParentApplicationBase. It almost seems like there is some other "hidden" place in the magic of the application framework that is making it think the base class is WindowsFormsApplicationBase rather than ParentApplicationBase.

I have searched both the general web and Stackoverflow in vain. The closest I found was this question [VB.NET - How do you change the namespace/class names for a "Windows application" from the default My.MyApplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130253/vb-net-how-do-you-change-the-namespace-class-names-for-a-windows-application), but that did not help.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: When you divide the definition of a class among several partial declarations, the compiler treats the class as the union of all its partial declarations. This applies not only to the members but also to the implementation, inheritance, and access level. A class can implement more than one interface, but it cannot inherit from more than one base class. Therefore, all Inherits statements must specify the same base class.  You decide which class should be the base class of your partial class, and remove from its partial declarations any Inherits statement that specifies a different base class.

Comment: To see more see **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d17t7cd.aspx** that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VB.NET compiler auto-generates code when you enable the application framework.  Which declares the My.MyApplication class and derives it from WindowsFormsApplicationBase. You cannot see this code, it only exists as MSIL and you'd have to use a decompiler (like ildasm) to see it.

But as the error tells you, the auto-generated My.MyApplication already has the base class pinned down and you can't change it anymore.  Only way to get ahead is to *disable* the application framework.  Nothing much to be worried about, the primary role of the class is to make the settings the project's Application properties tab work and you can simply change them by using code instead.

Project > Properties > Application tab > untick the "Enable application framework" checkbox.  Startup object > "Sub Main".  Add a new module and make it look similar to:

```
Module Entrypoint
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
        Dim app = New MyApplicationFramework()
        app.Run(args)
    End Sub
End Module

Class MyApplicationFramework
    Inherits ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
        Me.EnableVisualStyles = True
        Me.IsSingleInstance = False
        Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = True
        Me.ShutdownStyle = ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
        Me.MainForm = New Form1
    End Sub
End Class
```

Which uses the same values as the default settings in the Application tab.  Tweak as necessary.  And change the base class.

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I needed, particularly the explanation about "code only exists as MSIL".